# Phpmailer will not send attachments

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to make a form with a file upload line that sends as an attachment. I'm getting the email with the $body but no attachment I've looked over the code and done research everywhere so now I'm here, Any suggestions?

The PHP Code

```
if ( isset( $_FILES['upload'] ) && $_FILES['upload']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) {
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->AddAttachment( $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['upload']['name'] );
    }
```

The HTML Code

```
<form action="include/contractor.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">                
<label for="upload">File</label>
<input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" /></form>
```

Comment: Apparently "everywhere" didn't include the example scripts included with PHPMailer that show you exactly how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I just do this uploading file to one folder, and references this file with your permanent address.
Make a test with an existing file on your server and if it´s solve your problem modify your script to save file in a folder before send.

Answer (score 0):

I like bullet points so I will bullet the solution to your issue:

- [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)
- check your upload error code for file upload by using `print_r($_FILES['upload']['error']);` (you may be surprised)
- read https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps for guidance.
- Also read http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#114004 for details of safe file uploading.

As A note I would also say it could well be likely that your server system (might) have in place a restriction that temporary files freshly uploaded, `tmp_name` , their access is restricted. So use `move_uploaded_file` to save the file to a "real" destination before attaching to the email sender.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you need to actually have a way to upload the file to attach which would be some separate code than you have listed. When you add a file to Google mail, for example, you have to upload the file itself.

Without seeing the rest of your code I can't give a more explicit solution.